# How to prevent this warning message from revealing multiple times

Tags: javascript, createelement

As you can see in the image, the warning shows up whenever I trigger the click eventListener, naturally. But how can I make it show up only once. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```js
function eventListeners() {
form.addEventListener("submit", addTodo)
}
function showAlert(type, message) {
    const alert = document.createElement("div")
    alert.className = `alert alert-${type} d-inline p-1`
    alert.setAttribute("style", "border-radius: 2rem")
    alert.textContent = message
    form.appendChild(alert)
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert.remove()
    }, 1000)   
}
```

Comment: Problem is that you create a new alert every time `showAlert()` is called. What you should do is that check if there's an alert already shown. If it is, just change its contents instead of creating a new element.

Comment: @Yousaf Or rather, simply remove the existing before adding the new one, as otherwise you'd also have to cancel the old timeout to prevent it from removing the new message prematurely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Not a good solution.

Try this :

```
let isAlertBeingShown = false 

function eventListeners() {
form.addEventListener("submit", addTodo)
}
function showAlert(type, message) {
    if( isAlertBeingShown ) {
       //Do not show alert. Simply return.
       return; 
      // or you can do alert.remove here instead of return.

    }
    const alert = document.createElement("div")
    alert.className = `alert alert-${type} d-inline p-1`
    alert.setAttribute("style", "border-radius: 2rem")
    alert.textContent = message
    form.appendChild(alert);
    isAlertBeingShown = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert.remove();
        isAlertBeingShown = false;
    }, 1000)   
}
```

Comment: Works just fine, thans a lot. :))

Comment: Two problems. 1) There are possibly different alert types (hence "type" as argument), and 2) If you wait 900 ms and then press the button to get a new alert, it will disappear in 100 ms. The setTimeout should reset and created again. In other words, save the id for setTimeout, and use that to check if the alert is showing, instead of using `isAlertBeingShown`.

Comment: Rickard: thank you for the comment. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Instead of creating div and adding to form and then removing it again and again you can just add single div with `id` `message` in html for message and hide it using its css `display` property to `none` and then use javascript function to change message in div and show/hide it.

```js
let alert = document.querySelector('#message');
function showAlert(type, message) {
    alert.textContent = message;
    alert.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert.display = 'none';
        alert.textContent = '';
    }, 1000)   
}
```